# Почему бот перестал реагировать на команды, хотя на слова из словаря всё ещё реагирует?

Tags: python, бот, discord

Недавно добавил данные строки в своего бота:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def clear (ctx, amount = 100):
    await ctx.channel.purge (limit = amount)
```

И бот перестал работать. Пробовал убрать эту часть и дальше попробовать разобраться, но не помогло.

Вернее бот не перестал работать, а перестал реагировать на команды. Если бот видит слово из своего словаря, то спокойно реагирует на него, но на команды перестал реагировать. В консоли ошибок нет.

Даю полную версию кода:

```
#import
import discord; from discord.ext import commands

#command_prefix
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")


#dicts
coord_dict = ["корды", "база", "где база", "координаты", "координаты базы", "coords", "base", "where is base", "koordinati", "kordi", "kords", "koords", "кордс", "коордс", "базы координаты"]


#coonect_info
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("УРА Я СКОМПИЛИРОВАЛАСЬ! УРА<С САТАНА ПРИШЕЛ")

#hello_command
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def hello (ctx):
    await ctx.send (f"Hi (тут типа ник чела, который ввел команду)!\n\nI am bot-helper, which can you say to you all, what do you want about clan.\n\nПривет, (тут тоже)!\n\nЯ бот, который будет говорить все новости клана, которые мне извистны и которые ты пожелаешь!\n\nPrint: $help to show my commands!\nВведи $help для списка доступных команд!")

#ПОМЕТКА ДЛЯ СЕБЯ: НЕ ЗАБУДЬ РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ ИДЕЮ С УПОМИНАНЕМ В #hello_command!!!!

#coords_command
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def coords (ctx):
    await ctx.send ("Coords: тест\nКоординаты: zero zero 0. Coords: zero zero null")

#on_message checker
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in coord_dict:
        await message.channel.send("zero zero 0")

#clear_command
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def clear (ctx, amount = 100):
    await ctx.channel.purge (limit = amount)
        



#connect
token = open("token.txt", 'r').readline()
client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартная беда с ивентом on_message, все натыкаются, поэтому в официальном FAQ этот ответ даже первым пунктом: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#commands-extension

> Why does on_message make my commands stop working?
>
> Overriding the default provided `on_message` forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a `bot.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your `on_message.` For example:
>
> ```py
> @bot.event
> async def on_message(message):
>     # do some extra stuff here
>     await bot.process_commands(message)
> ```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]